# How to say that somebody crossed a street when the light was red?

Tags: phrase-choice

I have googled these expressions. I am not sure they are correct English.

> He crossed (the street) against the light. (heard on Seinfeld)
>
> He crossed (the street) against the red light.
>
> He crossed (the street) when the light was at red.
>
> He crossed (the street) on a red light."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're all correct. I'd say the first is the most common. You'd only use the second to make a particular emphasis as part of a larger conversation, but it's still correct.